# How to run tmux with /tmp full

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to run tmux on a remote machine. I have tmux installed into a conda environment. When I try to start a new session the usual way I get the error message: `error creating /tmp/tmux-23571 (No space left on device)`, so it seems like the issue is that the `/tmp` directory where tmux is trying to create the socket is full. Trying to follow instructions from https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Advanced-Use and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991768/tmux-shared-server-not-in-tmp, I tried the following:

```
touch /path/tmuxdir
tmux -S/path/tmuxdir new
```

when I do this, I don't see a new shell spawn, and the command exits, i.e. I get the same command line prompt back. However the exit status using `$?` is `0`.

The next thing I tried was
`export TMUX_TMPDIR=/path`. After doing so, if I run `tmux` to I get the same original error message as above stating that the `/tmp` directory is full.

I'm a little lost as to how to resolve this issue, can anyone help?

Comment: Please define "nothing happens". Does the command exit immediately and silently? If it exits, what is its exit status? Or does it hang? If it hangs, does it exit upon ctrl+c? How likely is it that `tmux` itself works, but the shell it tries to spawn doesn't? Does `tmux new 'sleep 5'` exit after 5 seconds? (try it with what you tried: one method, then the other).

Comment: Why not solve the issue of the full directory instead of working around it? tmux is for sure not the only application which is not happy about that fact.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your subordinate shell or other command that is launched by tmux also can't access /tmp and exits.

Try adding this to .tmux.conf to prevent it from exiting to see what's happening.

```
set -g remain-on-exit on
```

Also, if the subordinate shell respects TMPDIR, try setting TMPDIR=/path to have it also use a different directory.